# Heroku： MongoAPIError: database names cannot contain the character ' '

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mern

I am trying to deploy my node.js to Heroku.
But it shows this problem :

```
FOODTASTE_NS=sample_restaurants 

export default class FoodsDAO{
    static async injectDB(conn) {
      if (foods) {
        return
      }
      try {
        foods = await conn.db(process.env.FOODTASTE_NS).collection("restaurants")
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(
          `Unable to establish a collection handle in foodsDAO: ${e}`,
        )
      }
    }
```

Heroku throw a error says :

```
Unable to establish a collection handle in foodsDAO: MongoAPIError: database names cannot contain the character ' '
```

I am not sure should I need to change the database name in Mongodb?

Thank you

Comment: Spaces are not allowed in database names.  Try logging `process.env.FOODTASTE_NS` to make sure what it contains.

Comment: Hi@Joe Thanks for suggestion. I tried logging' process.env.FOODTASTE_NS‘. It shows 'sample_restaurants '.

Answer (score 0):

I  just solved this problem.
In the .env file, which contains all then environment variables. There is on variable called FOODTASTE_NS.

```
FOODTASTE_NS=sample_restaurants
```

If I didn't double-click this variable, I would not know there is a space character hide behind 'FOODTASTE_NS=sample_restaurants '. The correct answer is to delete that space and change it to 'FOODTASTE_NS=sample_restaurants'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).